# Why does glob pattern with double asterisk not match anything in subdirectories?

Tags: git, gitignore, glob

I'm trying to write a `.gitignore` rule to exclude some files in a particular directory that has multiple levels of subdirectories.

The folder structure looks something like this:

```
out
├─a
│ ├─source
│ │ ├─.keepme
│ │ ├─183597.txt
│ │ ├─271129.txt
│ │ └─288833.txt
│ └─parsed
│   ├─.keepme
│   ├─183597.csv
│   ├─271129.csv
│   └─288833.csv
├─b
│ └─(...)

(etc.)
```

I would like to keep the `.keepme` files (so that Git saves the directory structure), so I figure I'll write a rule to match anything under `out` that matches the pattern `?*.*`:

```
out/**/?*.*
```

However, this does not match any files.

I thought that `**` will match any number of subdirectories; why is this not working?

I'm running Git 1.8 in Bash 4.2 on a Fedora 18 VM.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to git the directory structure without any files?

Comment: What you could do, though, if you know that you won't ever want to add more files from `out` to git, is to simply add the `.keepme` files to the git index, commit that and then add `out/` to `.gitignore`. The `.keepme` files will be versioned as long as they remain in the repository, but no new files under `out/` will be added.

Comment: @EmilLundberg Good question.  These directories will store output files, and it's easier in this case to include the directory structure in the repository than have the program check for the presence of the files before saving the output.

Comment: How did you even get `out/**/*/*.*` to work? When I try it it excludes everything under `out` that contains a period.

Comment: @EmilLundberg Also good question.  This is partially due to munging the example data in the question to avoid publishing any possibly-sensitive information, and partially due to not testing the results as thoroughly as I could have.  I'm going to update my question to be a little less vague.

Comment: When you say "this doesn't match any files", you mean that no files are being ignored so that `git status -u` shows both `.keepme`  and `183597.txt`, right?

Comment: @thatotherguy Affirmative; that is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, make sure you are using Git 1.8.2 or up, since that's when `**` support was introduced.

It sounds like you're trying to exclude `.keepme` files by matching `*.*`. However, since `*` matches zero or more characters, it matches the empty string in front of the period in `.keepme`, including this file as well.

Maybe you intended it to work like `out/**/?*.*`

If you'd like to match all non-dotfiles, you can use `out/**/[!.]*` which will also include filenames without periods in them, like `Makefile`.

Comment: Or `out/**/[!.]*.*` which will match anything that contains a period and does not start with a period.

Comment: This is a good observation, thanks!  I will update my question to remove ambiguity (the part that I'm really interested in is why the `**` part isn't working the way I was expecting it to).

Answer (score 0):

I think that other guy's answer is a good lead. The pattern `out/**/[!.]*.*`, which should match everything that contains a period and does not start with a period, also works in my test in bash, Arch Linux:

```
$ find * -type f
out/a/source/4232352.txt
out/a/source/1312312.txt
out/a/source/4234234.txt
out/a/source/.keepme
out/a/parsed/1231222.csv
out/a/parsed/9593343.csv
out/a/parsed/5675675.csv
out/a/parsed/.keepme
$ cat .gitignore
out/**/[!.]*.*

$ git init && git add -A && git status --ignored
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   .gitignore
#   new file:   out/a/parsed/.keepme
#   new file:   out/a/source/.keepme
#
# Ignored files:
#   (use "git add -f <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   out/a/parsed/1231222.csv
#   out/a/parsed/5675675.csv
#   out/a/parsed/9593343.csv
#   out/a/source/1312312.txt
#   out/a/source/4232352.txt
#   out/a/source/4234234.txt
```

EDIT: It seems this actually doesn't work in the git bash bundled with the Windows version of git, there none of the above files are ignored by this `.gitignore`.

Comment: Very interesting.  What OS/shell are you running this on?  It doesn't seem to work on my system (result is that nothing is ignored).  I'll add my specs to the question as well.

Comment: Arch Linux, bash. I don't have the computer in question at my side at this moment, but I could come back to you later with more info if needed.